# how can i prevent replacing “&” with “&amp;” in magento url

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite

When i click on **add to compare** link on product listing page my url is changing from

```
magento.com/personal-care/face.html?dir=asc&order=Normal
```

to

```
magento.com/personal-care/face.html?dir=asc&amp;order=Normal
```

And the above link is breaking.

When I am making a small correction in the above url, by changing `&amp;` to `&`. Then it is working fine for me.

I also tried `RewriteRule ^(.*)&amp;(.*)$ /$1&$2 [L,R=301]` in .htaccess but no luck.

Comment: How does the button / link look like on the frontend. Is it an `<a>` tag with href attribute or is it using a JS function setLocation? If it's the latter I have the answer ready :)

Comment: it's in <a> tag, $this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product).

Comment: And the link is added in the href tag (`href="<?php $this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product) ?>"`)  or inside the onclick tag (`onclick="setLocation(<?php $this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product) ?>)"`)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&amp;(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1&%2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I found solution thank you for your help.

Comment: @PratikDhamane your welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

To overcome this problem i just rewrite `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/Product/CompareController.php`

replaced

> $this->_redirectReferer();

with

> $refererUrl = $this->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_REFERER');
>
> $this->_redirectUrl($refererUrl);

in `addAction()` function.

It seems `&` is replace with `&amp;` because of the `_getRefererUrl()` function in

`app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php`

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1&%2 [L,R=301]` is taking to `index.php` always.
If I'm on the product page URL, I need to keep it, so for example:

> www.domain.com/product.html?a1=v1&a2=v2

is taking me to

> www.domain.com/index.php/?a1=v1&a2=v2